# Inequality between Independent Erlang random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have two Independent erlang random variables as follows,

$$X \sim {\rm Erl}(n, \lambda) \text{ and } Y \sim {\rm Erl}(m, \mu)$$

Here $\lambda$ is the rate parameter ie,
$f_X(x) = \lambda^n \frac {e^{-\lambda x }  x^{n-1}} {(n-1)!}$

I want to calculate $F (n, m) = \mathbb P(X < Y ).$

I tried to do the following,

$$\int \mathbb P(X < Y \mid X=x ) \cdot f_X(x) \, dx$$

which on simplification is giving me

$$\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} {n+r-1 \choose r} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^n \left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^r.$$

But the answer given is 
$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+m-1} {n+m-1 \choose k} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^k \left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{n+m-k-1}.$$

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Where you wrote $\Pr(Y<X/X=x)$ I surmised that you meant $\Pr(Y<x\mid X=x)$ and changed it to that. $\qquad$

Comment: yeah the expression ${\mathbb P}(X < Y/X=x )$ is equal to ${\mathbb P}(x < Y )$

Comment: Note that $$ \int_0^\infty \Pr(X<Y \mid X=x) f_X(x)\, dx = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(X<Y\mid X)) = \Pr(X<Y),$$ the marginal probability that $X<Y$.  Did you reduce that marginal probability to that integral and then set about evaluating the integral?  If not, you might just want to work directly on finding that marginal probability by other means. That will tell you the value of the integral. $\qquad$

Comment: The expression $\int{\mathbb P}(X < Y/X=x ) f_{X}(x)dx = \int \sum_{r=0}^{m-1} \frac{e^{-x/\mu}  x^r}{\mu^r r!}   f_{X}(x)dx$  After this we can interchange the summation and integral  to integrate x over o to infinity        @Michael Hardy

Comment: It is vulgar to write $3*5$ when you can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times5$.  Use of the asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for situations when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard. $\qquad$

Comment: Did you get the answer? @Michael Hardy

Comment: The Erlang distribution is the Gamma distribution in a case where the exponent is a non-negative integer. The Gamma distribution gets parametrized in either of two ways, so that the second parameter could be either the scale parameter or the rate, which is the reciprocal of the scale, thus: $$\text{either } \frac 1 {\Gamma(n)} \left( \frac x \alpha \right)^{n-1} e^{-x/\alpha}\  \frac{dx} \alpha \text{ or } \frac 1 {\Gamma(n)} (\alpha x)^{n-1} e^{-\alpha x} ( \alpha\, dx).$$ Which of those do you have in mind? $\qquad$

Comment: Here the second parameter is the rate parameter. Therefore $f_X(x)=\lambda^n \frac {e^{-\lambda x} x^{n-1}} {(n-1)!}$

Comment: That's not a scale parameter; that's a rate parameter.  If $\displaystyle f_X(x)\,dx = \frac{ e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda x)^{n-1} (\lambda\, dx) }{(n-1)!} \text{ for } x\ge 0,$ then $1/\lambda$ is the scale parameter and $\lambda$ is the rate. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Erlang PDF comes from the Poisson process. In fact, $X\sim \mathrm{Erl}(n, \lambda)$ means that $X$ is the $n$-th arrival time in the Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. This means that the number of arrivals in a given time interval $[0,x]$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $x\lambda$.

Using $Y\sim \mathrm{Erl}(m,\mu)$, we have for $x>0$,
$$
P(x<Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{e^{-x\mu}(x\mu)^k}{k!}.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(X<Y)&=\int_0^{\infty} P(x<Y)  \lambda^n \frac {e^{-\lambda x }  x^{n-1}} {(n-1)!} dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{e^{-x\mu}(x\mu)^k}{k!}   \lambda^n \frac {e^{-\lambda x }  x^{n-1}} {(n-1)!}dx \\
&=\lambda^n \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{k+n-1}{n-1}\mu^k\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)x}x^{k+n-1}}{(k+n-1)!} dx \\
&=\lambda^n \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{k+n-1}{n-1}\mu^k \frac1{(\lambda+\mu)^{k+n}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{k+n-1}{n-1} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^n\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^k.  \ \ \ (*) \end{align}
$$
This expression seems different, but this is equivalent to:
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n+m-1} {n+m-1 \choose k} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^k \left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{n+m-k-1}. \ \ \ \ (**)$$

Let $T\sim NB(n, \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu})$. This is the time of $n$-th success, with probability of success in each trial is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$. Let $S\sim B(n+m-1,\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu})$. This is the number of successes in $n+m-1$ trials, with probability of success in each trial is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$. Note that
$$
n\leq T\leq n+m-1 \Longleftrightarrow n\leq S\leq n+m-1.
$$
The formula $(*)$ is the expression for $P(n\leq T\leq n+m-1)$ and the second formula $(**)$ is $P(n\leq S\leq n+m-1)$.
Thus, we must have
$$
P(n\leq T\leq n+m-1) = P(n\leq S\leq n+m-1). 
$$
This shows that $(*)$ and $(**)$ are equivalent.

A special case $n=m=1$ is easier to calculate:
In this case $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim \mathrm{Exp}(\mu)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(X<Y)&=\int_0^\infty P(x<Y) \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx\\
&=\lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\lambda+\mu)x} dx = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}.
\end{align}
$$
There is a reasoning that leads directly to one of the binomial or negative binomial distributions.

Let $\{A_t\}$ and $\{B_t\}$ be Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively. Then we can consider the arrivals from $\{A_t\}$ as success and the arrivals from $\{B_t\}$ as failures. The probability of success is $P(X<Y)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$. The event that $n$-th arrival time from $\{A_t\}$ is less than $m$-th arrival time from $\{B_t\}$ can be described as

The $n$-th success happens before the $m$-th failure. $\ \ \ \ \rm (I)$

The formulas $(*)$ and $(**)$ both represent the probability of the event $ \rm(I)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @i707107 , As you said in the power, n and r are switched and what answer you gave to show they are equivalent is right . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hasty stab at it, which probably has some details wrong.  An essential step is the binomial theorem.  Note that one can never pull out of a sum a factor that depends on the index of summation, nor pull out of an integral a factor that depends on the variable with respect to which one integrates.  And it should be clear from the start that the bottom line should depend on $\mu$ and $\lambda$ only through the ratio $\mu/\lambda$, as does in fact happend below and also in the answers mentioned in the question.

\begin{align}
\Pr(X<Y) & = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(X<Y \mid X)) \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^\infty \Pr(X<Y\mid X=x) f_X(x)\, dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_x^\infty f_Y(y)\,dy \right) f_X(x) \, dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_x^\infty \frac 1 {(m-1)!} (\mu y)^{m-1} e^{-\mu y} (\mu\, dy) \right) \frac 1 {(n-1)!} (\lambda x)^{n-1} e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda \, dx) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(m-1)!(n-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \int_{\mu v/\lambda}^\infty u^{m-1} e^{-u}\,du \right) v^{n-1} e^{-v} \, dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(m-1)!(n-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty \left( w + \frac{\mu v} \lambda \right)^{m-1} e^{-(w + (\mu v/\lambda))} \, dw \right) v^{n-1} e^{-v} \, dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(m-1)!(n-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu v/\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m-1} k w^k \left( \frac{\mu v} \lambda \right)^{m-1-k} e^{-w} \, dw \right) v^{n-1} e^{-v} \, dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(m-1)!(n-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( e^{-\mu v/\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m-1} k \left( \frac{\mu v} \lambda \right)^{m-1-k} \int_0^\infty w^k e^{-w}\,dw \right) v^{n-1} e^{-v}\,dv \\[10pt]
& =  \frac 1 {(m-1)!(n-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( e^{-\mu v/\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m-1} k \left( \frac{\mu v} \lambda \right)^{m-1-k} k! \right) v^{n-1} e^{-v}\,dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac {(\mu/\lambda)^{m-1-k}} {(m-1-k)!} \int_0^\infty v^{m+n-k-2} e^{-v(1+ \mu/\lambda)} \, dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac {(\mu/\lambda)^{m-1-k}} {(m-1-k)!} \frac{(m+n-k-2)!}{\left( 1 + \frac \mu \lambda \right)^{m+n-k-1}} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {(n-1)!} \sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1} \frac {(\mu/\lambda)^\ell} {\ell!} \frac{(\ell+n-1)!}{\left( 1 + \frac \mu \lambda \right)^{\ell+n}} \qquad (\text{where } \ell = m-1-k) \\[10pt]
& = \left( \frac \lambda {\lambda + \mu} \right)^n\  \sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1} \frac{\left( \frac\mu{\lambda+\mu} \right)^\ell}{\ell!}
\end{align}

Comment: Actually it's from $\ell=0$ to $m-1$. $\qquad$

Comment: The last line should have $(l+n-1)! / l!$, since $(l+n-1)!$ and $(n-1)!$ don't cancel out each other.